# Arranging the string of a list in a required format in python

Tags: python, list

Actually i am parsing some html pages by using scrapy, i have used xpath and fetched some address from some html tag and the result is in the following form

```
result = ["Hno 4-50, Plot No 301, Swathi Pooja Homes,Beside Rajadhani Theater, Vikas Nagar,Dilsukhnagar,Hyderabad","Mr Sravan"]
```

And i want to join the string so i had done below

```
final_result = ','.join(result)
```

and got the following result

```
final_result = "Hno 4-50, Plot No 301, Swathi Pooja Homes,Beside Rajadhani Theater, Vikas Nagar,Dilsukhnagar,Hyderabad,Mr Sravan"
```

Here as we can observe that the name in the `final_result` (address) `Mr Sravan` is at the end, but generally the name should be before the door or house number in any contacts  anywhere right?, so irrespective of number of strings in the list after joining it i should get the name at starting, is there any way to do this? can anyone please let me know how to do this?

**Edited Code:**

Presently i am parsing four urls at a time, so when i have used xpath(or related) and fetched address from different urls and the result(for example) is as below for each url

```
final_result = ['Addess_2','Newyork', 'Mr T.Jamal(Name)']
               ['Mr T. Jamal(Name)', 'Addres_1','Extra info'] 
               ['Addres_3','Mr T. Jamal(Name)','Extra info','Related scope'] 
               ['Addres_4','Extra info','Mr T. Jamal(Name)','Related info'] 
               ['Addres_5','Extra info','Related info']  # No name
               ['Addres_6','Extra info1','Related info1']  # No name
```

Here for all urls in parsing address want to write the code which works for all lists above

Comment: What should happen if "Mr" isn't in the list? Also, this is the 3rd somewhat non-trivial change to the original question .. at some point you probably want to post a new question :)

Comment: Ok this is final and i will not change the question again, if there is no name in the list just need to print the remaining strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
  final_result = result[-1] + ', ' + ''.join(result[:-1])
```

yielding:

```
Mr Sravan, Hno 4-50, Plot No 301, Swathi Pooja Homes,Beside Rajadhani Theater, Vikas Nagar,Dilsukhnagar,Hyderabad
```

--  **UPDATE** --

This should find the "Mr" string anywhere in your original list and make it work the way you want.

```
rs = ','.join(result).split(',')
idx = [i for i,j in enumerate(rs) if j.strip().startswith('Mr')][0]
final_result = (rs[idx] +',' + ','.join(rs[1:idx] + rs[idx+1:])).strip()
print final_result
```

This works with the 4 test strings provided in the update post by OP

--  **UPDATE 2** OP changes question so that "Mr" may not be in list  --

This code will detect if Mr is in the list and move it to the front as above. It will also detect if it's not in the list and avoid a index out of bounds condition. See output below.

Test strings:

```
result = ['Addres_4','Extra info','Mr T. Jamal(Name)','Related info'] 
result = ['Addres_4','Extra info','T. Jamal(Name)','Related info']
```

code:

```
rs = ','.join(result).split(',')
idx = [i for i,j in enumerate(rs) if j.strip().startswith('Mr')]

if len(idx) == 1:  # we found "Mr" in the list
    idx = idx[0]
    final_result = (rs[idx] +',' + ','.join(rs[1:idx] + rs[idx+1:])).strip()
else: # We didn't find "Mr" in the list .. adjust output to your needs
    final_result = (','.join(rs).strip())

print final_result
```

yield respectively:

```
Mr T. Jamal(Name),Extra info,Related info
Addres_4,Extra info,T. Jamal(Name),Related info
```

Comment: What if we don't know the position of name in the list because during fetching the name is in middle of the list sometimes and for sure the name starts with Mr

Comment: @shivakrishna I just ran my code on your 4 test strings, and it worked.

Comment: wheni ran my complete code, but at idx some times idx = [i for i,j in enumerate(rs) if j.strip().startswith('Mr')][0]
 exceptions.IndexError: list index out of range is displaying

Comment: @shivakrishna This didn't happen with any of your 4  test strings right? Make sure there's a "Mr" in your list. Can you show the list where you had the problem?

Comment: @ Levon: Yes you are right(Dont mind i am asking questions continuosly) really now the problem is some times there is no Name in the list actually so its displaying list index out of error.For the list with strings this method is working perfect but with name  starting with Mr is absent it will show list index out of range error right ?

Comment: @shivakrishna I'll update my answer, but you may have to modify it to fit your final needs (esp in the case Mr is not in the string)

Comment: @shivakrishna Glad we got it straightened out.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this :

```
final_result = ','.join(result[-1:] + result[:-1])


>>> 'Mr Sravan,Hno 4-50, Plot No 301, Swathi Pooja Homes,Beside Rajadhani Theater, Vikas Nagar,Dilsukhnagar,Hyderabad'
```

EDIT: 
Following your comment, if you know that the name is located at the rank `i`, it could be done like this :

```
result = ["is", "now", "the name", "at", "first", "place", ":)"]
i = 2
' '.join(result[i:i+1] + result[:i] + result[i+1:])
'the name is now at first place :)'
```

Comment: I think that works if the name string is at end of the list, but what if the name jumbles in the list, i mean some times the name is in middle of the list and sometimes at end ....  so anyway the name starts with Mr

Comment: @shivakrishna there is no *middle* in the list you gave as an example. It consists of two strings. Was that a mistake?

Comment: @shivakrishna if you known where is located the name, it could be different

Comment: Hey no actually the answer is acceptable, but i had told about my problem some times i got 4 strings in a list and name is at 3 position and what to do in this situation,so i was confused.......

Comment: @Cédric Julien: Yes if we known the position of the field the above is applicable but sometimes the poition of Mr Sravan is changing, so can i know what to do in that situation

Comment: @shivakrishna : I edited my answer with a solution a little more generic, but if you can't determine where the name is located it will be a little more difficult ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
def name_first(alist):
    """Get the part of the list that begins with 'Mr', then the rest."""
    for i, el in enumerate(alist):
        if el.startswith('Mr'):
            yield alist.pop(i)
            break
    for el in alist:
        yield el
```